# How to make proper use of custom colormaps when plotting segmented lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot lines, that change their color gradually depending on a certain value `threshold`. For example if `threshold > 0.3` plot `line` in full `colormap` from `blue` to `red`. But if `threshold = 0.15` only plot line in the colors of half the `colormap`, starting with `blue`. That would mean the `line` would use colors from `blue` to `violet`.

Unfortunately my `colormap` changes when I change the `line`. I am purposely using a custom `colormap` because I need `blue, red` colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# x,y coordinates
x1 = 0
x2 = 1
y1 = 0
y2 = 1

# create segments from coordinates
x_coords = np.linspace(x1, x2, 100)
y_coords = np.linspace(y1, y2, 100)

# "resolution"
res_ar = np.linspace(x1, x2, len(x_coords))

# reshape array to fit matplotlib segmentation
points = np.array([x_coords, y_coords]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# create custom colormap
cvals = [0., 1.]
colors = ['blue', 'red']
norm = plt.Normalize(min(cvals), max(cvals))
tuples = list(zip(map(norm, cvals), colors))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', tuples)

# plot segmented line
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap)
lc.set_array((res_ar))
ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I change the `line` coordinates the `cmap` is also changed to fit the line:

```
x1 = 0
x2 = 0.5
y1 = 0
y2 = 0.5
```

[image]

But how do I change the `line` without changing the `cmap`? The `line` is supposed to depend on the `cmap`, not the other way round.

Comment: If you always want to use the same norm, use `norm = plt.Normalize(0, 1)` instead of letting it depend on the data values.

Comment: `cvals = [0., 1.]`  does the same thing, if I'm not mistaking

Comment: Probably you need to use the norm in `LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)`

Comment: @JohanC yes, that was the problem. Do you want to post an answer :-) ?

Comment: I think it would be very difficult for others with a similar problem to find this exact question.